# error using parallel.p​ool.consta​nt/get value MATLAB (parallel computing toolbox)

Tags: matlab

so this is my code (not sure about function handle in parfeval). The error I get is on line 11. I dont understand the error

```
poolobj=parpool('my_cluster',8);
[up, op]=ndgri(1e-3:1e-2:1,1e-3:1e-2:1);
up=reshape(up, [1,size(up,1)*size(up,2)]);
up=reshape(up, [1,size(up,1)*size(up,2)]);
z=rand(5,5e3);
addAttachedFiles('<path to my function/cores_random.m');%%to add the function files to workers on the pool
C1=parallel.pool.Constant(z);%%use parallel.pool.Constant to copy these variables into workers
U2=parallel.pool.Constant(up);
O2=parallel.pool.Constant(op);

for i=1:size(up,2)
f1(i)=parfeval(poolobj,@cores_random,3,U2.value(i),O2.Value(i),C1.Value(1,:)); %%line 11
f2(i)=parfeval(poolobj,@cores_random,3,U2.value(i),O2.Value(i),C1.Value(2,:));
f3(i)=parfeval(poolobj,@cores_random,3,U2.value(i),O2.Value(i),C1.Value(3,:));
f4(i)=parfeval(poolobj,@cores_random,3,U2.value(i),O2.Value(i),C1.Value(4,:));
f5(i)=parfeval(poolobj,@cores_random,3,U2.value(i),O2.Value(i),C1.Value(5,:));
end 

for j=1:size(up,2):-1:1
    [idx1,u1,o1,ep1]=fetchNext(f1);
    [idx2,u2,o2,ep2]=fetchNext(f2);
    [idx3,u3,o3,ep3]=fetchNext(f3);
     [idx4,u4,o4,ep4]=fetchNext(f4);
     [idx5,u5,o5,ep5]=fetchNext(f5);
end
```

I got an error

```
{Error using paralle.pool.Constant/get.Value The value of a parallel.pool.Constant is only available on the workers. 
Error in main_parallel_norm (line 11) 
f1(i)=parfeval(poolobj,@cores_random,3,U2.value(i),O2.Value(i),C1.Value(1,:));
```

the function cores_random is  as the following:

```
[uu,oo,ep]=cores_random(up,op,z)
%%doing some calculations here
%%z is of size 1*1e3 
%%up is scalar op is scalar 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the `Value` property of a `parallel.pool.Constant` is available only on the workers. As written, your `parfeval` requests are trying to access it on the client. Briefly, your code looks like this:

```
c = parallel.pool.Constant(42);
f = parfeval(pool, @myFcn, 1, c.Value);
```

This forces the client to evaluate `c.Value` when setting up the `parfeval` call.

What you should do instead is pass the `Constant` itself into the `parfeval` request, and then access the `Value` field on the workers. One way to do that is like this:

```
c = parallel.pool.Constant(42);
f = parfeval(pool, @(const) myFcn(const.Value), 1, c);
```

This ensures that the `const.Value` expression is only evaluated on the workers. (Alternatively, you could modify `myFcn` to know that it needs to call `const.Value` on its input arguments.)